# KVO in Swift custom notification center

Tags: swift

Using the observer pattern I'm trying to make my own notification center.

The only way I can call the observer's value which is a function seems to be:

```
observer.value(notification.notificationName, observer.value)
```

This can't be right, the observer.value does not need to be passed observer.value so what can be the right answer?

```
typealias Observer = (String, Any) -> Void

class MyNotification {
    var notificationName: String
    init(name: String) {
        notificationName = name
    }
}

class MyNotificationCenter {
    // var observers = [Observer]() // using an array here does not work
    var observers = [String: Observer]()

    // given
    // for notification name, the block to be executed when the notification is received
    func addObserver(forName name: String, usingBlock block: @escaping Observer) {
        // add observer to the array
        observers[name] = block
    }

    // given
    func removeObserver(forName name: String) {
        if observers[name] != nil {
            observers[name] = nil
        }
    }

    // not given
    func postNotification(notification: MyNotification) {
        // For each object in the observer array, call its processNotification() method
        for observer in observers {
            observer.value(notification.notificationName, observer.value)
        }
    }
}

class Boss {
    let obs1: Observer = { (name, data) in
        print (name, "HERE")
    }

    init() {
        notification.addObserver(forName: "test", usingBlock: obs1)
    }
}

var notification = MyNotificationCenter()
let boss = Boss()
notification.postNotification(notification: MyNotification(name: "test notification"))
```

Question - in the above code observer.value(notification.notificationName, observer.value) is incorrect since observer.value should in no way need to be passed observer.value, so what is the right interpretation of this code?

Comment: Unrelated, but `if observers[name] != nil {
            observers[name] = nil
        }` can be just `observers[name] = nil`